# Setting font size of amsart documentclass have no effect

Tags: fontsize, amsart

Consider

```
\documentclass[20pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

No matter how I change the 20pt to anything, I cannot see any effect in the pdf output.

Does anyone know how to change the font size of the text in "amsart"?

Comment: there is not support file for this size, only for 10, 11 and 12pt. Try the extsize package.

Comment: Just curious: what kind of use case do you have in mind for a main document font size of 20 pt?

Comment: @Mico Just an example. I want to see clearly whether it works, so better to set a bigger number.

Answer (score 3):

The `amsart` class only supports

```
8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt
```

as font size options. The first two just for preprints when you really want to save paper at the expense of readability. An unknown option is neglected and you're warned about that in the log file

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [20pt].
```

The font size is then the default 10pt.

If you want a different main font size, I recommend the [`fontsize`](https://texdoc.org/serve/fontsize/0) package.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[fontsize=20pt]{fontsize}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

For Computer Modern fonts, `fix-cm` is needed as shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different options:

If you only need a larger font size in part of a document, you can always wrap that text in `\begin{Huge}` and `\end{Huge}`. (Note: see comment below from David Carlisle; I have updated my answer with that information.)

If you need to control the line spacing as well, you can use the `\fontsize{}{}` command. See the below MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5]{amsart}

\begin{document}
Two roads diverged in a wood, and I, I took the one less travelled by, and that has made all the difference.

\begin{Huge}
Two roads diverged in a wood, and I, I took the one less travelled by, and that has made all the difference.

\end{Huge}

\fontsize{20}{36}\selectfont
Two roads diverged in a wood, and I, I took the one less travelled by, and that has made all the difference.

\end{document}
```

Just a note: the last example (`\fontsize{}{}`) may not be considered a best practice.

[image]

Comment: you should always have a blank line before `\end{<size>)` or the line spacing will be  wrong

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. I did not realize that, and have updated the code and image in my answer.